# On z/OS, what are the valid characters for a userid?

Tags: zos

I have been unable to determine what the valid characters are for a z/OS userid.
Does it follow the same rules as a dataset qualifier or is it less/more restrictive?
I know until recently, userids could only be 7 characters but saw that this is now extended to 8, however I am unsure what the valid characters are in the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A RACF User ID can consist of A-Z, 0-9, #, $, or @.

It appears through testing that USERIDs are more restrictive than dataset names as the hyphen character is not a valid USERID character. Through testing, I was unable to create an ID named ST-VEN on a RACF system in z/OS 2.5.

See here for more info:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=users-user-naming-conventions

Comment: Thanks! This begs the question of whether a 'RACF User ID' can have different characters than a 'TSO or MVS User ID'. Do they not all need to be the same? Can I associate an MVS Userid with a different TSO Userid with a different RACF userid and maybe with a different UNIX System Services Userid or are they one and all the same?

Comment: An interesting observation is that I could create a userid that started with a numeric digit, but then I would not be able to create any datasets using my userid as the high level qualifier.

Comment: They're all one and the same, but if you used some other security manager instead of RACF it could have different rules.

The rules for TSO are actually *more* restrictive than RACF's, though, and JES2's even more so:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=tsoe-selecting-user-id
- No longer than seven or eight characters based on the installation setting
- First character - Must be an alphabetic or national
- With JES2 a user ID:
- Cannot be in the format Rnnnnnn or Nnnnnnn
- Should not be in the format Unnnnnn

Comment: @StevenPerva Would you please delete your comment which is identical to your answer. It is of no additional value.